# Validating information in HTML - Code Positioning

Tags: php, html

I am having trouble getting my code validation to work. I have written validation for a name, surname and email address, however, I don't know where to insert a command for the php code to be called in my main html.

I was thinking I have to add an action into a form like this:

```
<body>
    <div class="logo"></div>
    <div class="login-block">
        <h1>Create Account</h1>
        <form action="insert_data.php" method="post">
        <form action="validate_data.php">
            <input type="text" value="" placeholder="First Name" name="first_name" />
            <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Last Name" name="last_name" />
            <input type="email" value="" placeholder="E-mail Address" name="email_address" />
```

However, I don't know if that is correct. All three of the validation notes are saved in a file called 'validate_data.php'.

My code for name and surname validation is pretty much the same, with the main 'name' spaces changed:

```
<?php
$first_name = test_input($_POST["first_name"]);
if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$first_name)) {
$first_nameErr = "Incorrect name format."; 
}
?>
```

and for my email:

```
<?php
$email_address = test_input($_POST["email_address"]);
if (!filter_var($email_address, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $email_addressErr = "Invalid email format."; 
}
?>
```

Is there any particular place I will have to call this? Or am I just doing some stupid mistake and missing it?

Comment: that name validation will fail many names

Comment: `if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$first_name)) {` doesn't do what you think it does. You want it to look like this: `if (preg_match("/[^a-zA-Z\s]+/",$first_name)) {`.

Comment: In order to answer your question: are you asking where you should put your validation code? or are you asking why your validation isn't working?

Comment: Sorry my bad, I should of explained it better. I'm asking where I should put it in the HTML so it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't put it in the HTML unless you are sending the page to itself, in which case it is usually best to put the PHP at the top of the page. It would need to be named as a `.php` page not `.html` then. That way if, for example, you wanted to make the values of the form stay as what was submitted you could echo them after they are cleaned up by setting the textbox value

```
 value="<?php echo $first_name; ?>"
```

for example. If you are submitting to `insert_data.php` all the PHP just lives on that page at the top. You seem to have too many `<form actions` - you can only submit once. Best to put your cleanup code at the top of `insert_data.php` and submit to that.

If it is on the same page you would need to wrap it in

```
    if( isset($_POST["first_name"])){
     // do the cleanup
    }
```

or you will get messages for the empty inputs which have not had the chance to be submitted as the page loads. And do the same for the email address which you definitely don't want to have blank if you are subsequently going to use it for a mail form's `Reply-To:` address (the `From:` should always be an address on your server or you will be back here posting wondering why it doesn't work!)

You could `include` the validation script but that is possibly a bit risky and for the length of the code there is probably little advantage in having it as an include. Risks of including unsafely: http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=199419

You would then use - assuming your includes are in a folder called `inc/`

```
include "inc/validate_data.php";
```

at the top of your `insert_data.php` page - without the brackets shown in that article - it is a declaration, not a function.

Another good article on `includes`:

http://green-beast.com/blog/?p=144

If you were looping out posts, for example, the code to do that would be somewhere among the HTML inside the div where you wanted them to appear.