# PHP code isn't allowing multiple input values to send through my form

Tags: php, html

I am running into a wall with an application I have built.  I am brand new to PHP (less than 1 month) and I have written a very complex form with the help of a mentor.  Due to a confidentiality agreement I cannot send my entire code here for an example.  Specifically the issue I am having is that my form isn't able to send multiple values to two different input "slots". It will send a singular input value to the database, but it should be registering the different values inputted.

```
<?php                        
{
foreach($results['tags'] as $part){
if ($part['category'] == "Part"){
?>
<tr>
<td><?= $part['Part']; ?></td>
<td class="text-center"><?= $product['Amount']; ?></td>
<td><input type="text" name=$product['Val1'] /></td>
<td><input type="text" name=$product['Val2'] /></td>
</tr>

<?php
    }
      }

         }

            ?>
```

My mentor suggested this as an answer but I am not sure what he means:
"It seems like the [val1/2] needs to be tied to the product instead of the transaction. Right now, it’s not inside that “tags” section. Does that make sense?"

Comment: unless you literally want your two field names to be named with the chars `$`, `p`, `r`, `o`, etc..., you probably want to surround them with `<?=` and `?>`...

Comment: On newer versions of php it seems that long tags are compulsory so it would need to be `name="<?php echo $product['Val2'] ?>"` and the same on other inputs, classes etc. `htmlspecialchars()` should probably also be used around the data as you will be echoing it.

Comment: @SheaPrice If you are new to php this might be of some use. Good luck! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34321429/validating-information-in-html-code-positioning/34323785#34323785

Comment: There is a possibility that your php set-up doesn't support short tags if thhis scrit has never worked properly http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/151661/is-it-bad-practice-to-use-tag-in-php might explain that.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I won't be able to test this until next week, I will update once I have resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to name your vars with `$`. I suppose you want to output php values there, so change your string to look like this:

```
<td><input type="text" name="<?= $product['Val1'] ?>"/></td>
```

Comment: I've tried this and I get an error that goes to a different portion of my code (which works flawlessly until I try to implement this).                                         *Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in www.index.php line xx

Comment: Well, it means there's something with `foreach ($<this_var> as $something) {`

Comment: You are absolutely correct... any idea how to troubleshoot that? I've been messing with it for 2 days and I'm not getting anywhere.

Comment: Can you `var_dump` the `$results` variable?

Comment: Yes @switcher.  The $results variable is correct.  It parses a json string.  I'm wondering if the issue could be on the other side of the code (the backend that's pushing me information) and how it receives these inputs?  Is that a plausible issue?

Answer (score 1):

"$" represents PHP variable and hence it needs to be inside the php tag. Also remember to enclose the echo value with quotes(").

```
<?php       
     foreach($results['tags'] as $part) {
        if ($part['category'] == "Part") {
?>
<tr>
    <td><?= $part['Part']; ?></td>
    <td class="text-center"><?= $product['Amount']; ?></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="<?= $product['Val1']; ?>" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="<?= $product['Val2']; ?>" /></td>
</tr>
<?php
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: I believe this may be what I am wanting.  I will test next week and update.  Thank you.

Comment: None of these have worked for me, and ended up unfortunately breaking my working code.

Answer (score 1):

The answer was I needed to iterate them since they aren't arrays and append them to the string.

This was accomplished thanks to [@SonnY](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35231898/5669251)

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
function sendData() {
  var inputs = document.getElementById('equipment-table').getElementsByTagName('input'),
      data = [],
      name, val1, val2;

  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    if ( inputs[i].type === 'submit') {
      continue;
    }

    if ( inputs[i].value ) {
      name = inputs[i].name.split('-val');
      val1 = inputs[i].name.split('val1');

      if (val1.length > 1) {
        data.push({name: name[0], val1: inputs[i].value});
      }
      else {
        data.push({name: name[0], val2: inputs[i].value});
      }
    }
  }

  window.setTimeout(function() {
    sendData();
  },30000);
}

sendData();
```

Answer (score 0):

***Merry Christmas***

Since, Not Much Data Provided. I am assuming from my side. Hope it helps.

Place the value in `value` attribute. Give name as array type. Like `Slot1[]`, `Slot2[]` .. 
Since, There may be more than 1 value for `Val1`, so name is of array type.

```
<form action='SubmitSomePage.php' method='POST'>

    <?php                        
    {
        foreach($results['tags'] as $part)
        {
            if ($part['category'] == "Part")
            {?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?= $part['Part']; ?></td>
                    <td class="text-center"><?= $product['Amount']; ?></td>
                    <td><input type="text" value="<?=$product['Val1'];?>" name='Slot1[]'/></td>
                    <td><input type="text" value="<?= $product['Val2'];?>" name='Slot2[]' /></td>
                </tr>
                <?php
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
    .
    .
    <input type='submit' value='Submit Details'>

</form>
```

**SubmitSomePage.php**

```
<?

$slot1 = $_POST['Slot1'];
$slot2 = $_POST['Slot2'];

$TotalSlot1 = sizeof($slot1);

for($i = 0; $i<$TotalSlot1;$i++)
{
    $slot1Value = $slot1[$i];       
    $slot2Value = $slot2[$i];

    $Query = "INSERT INTO TableName Set Val1='$slot1Value', Val2='$slot2Value'";
    //Execute Query Here.   
}
?>
```