# Form if then Else/ifElse HTML on submit

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a form that I need to act in specific ways. Example: User brings equipment back: I don't want that to show up in my form. User takes equipment out: I want it to generate to my form, they enters some information, form sends information to database. User takes equipment out: it too generates said form, he doesn't enter any information, form submits information after 20 sec, information is in database.

I was doing a simple page refresh to get the information into my form but that was pulling all the equipment that had been brought into the warehouse that day. So I commented that out and then I would get stuck on my ajax page.

I then tried creating a new php page that had a 301 page refresh and that worked to get the page back to my index page, however, my form wasn't working properly and so I commented out the auto submit and now my form works great... except I can't fulfill this last requirement where the page will submit the data if the user forgets to put his equipment information in.

I'm looking to do an if/then/else type of page submission. However, I can't figure out how to do one purely in either php or html. This is what I have figured out so far but it doesn't work and I know I'm way off somewhere.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<!--This is the one that is currently commented out in my code
<script type="text/javascript">
 window.setTimeout(function() {
 window.location = 'index.php'},1000*2);
</script>
</body>
</html> -->

  //This is my pipe dream 
   <?php
   if (isset($_POST['action'])) {
        switch ($_POST['action']) {
                    case ‘DONE’:
                        document.getElement('formSubmit').submit();
                        break;
            }
              } else {
                 <script type="text/javascript">
                     window.setTimeout(function(){
                     document.getElement('formSubmit').submit();
                },1000*30);
                 </script>
           }

          ?>
```

I don't know that much about jQuery other than going through a codecademy, and I know even less javascript.  I'm a database person that got "conned" into building an advanced form/webpage. So I'm learning PHP, CSS, jQuery and HTML as I code.

Index.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name=“Warehouse 3962” content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript">
<!—window.setTimeout(function(){
              document.getElement(‘formSubmit').submit();
              },1000*30); —>
</script>
</head>
<body>
<section class="w">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="small columns">
            <img src="logo.png" />
            <h3 class="green">Users</h3>
        </div>

        <h6>Warehouse 3962</h6>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="small columns">
            <form action="ajax.php" method="post" id="formSubmit">
                <table id="equipment-table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Equipment</th>
                            <th>Amount</th>
                            <th>Val1</th>
                            <th>Val2</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>
                        <?php foreach 
                        ($results['tags'] as $equipment) {
                            if ($equipment['category'] == "Part") { ?>

                                <tr>
                            <td><?= $equipment['Amount']; ?></td>
                <td class="text-center"><?= $equipment[‘quantity']; ?></td>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="val1" /></td>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="val2" /></td>
                                </tr>

                            <?php } // end if
                        } // end foreach ?>

                        <tr>
        <td colspan="4" style="text-align: right;"><input      type="submit" class="button" name="DONE" value="DONE" /></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: these curly quotes `case ‘DONE’` if they're part of your real code, are failing you. Plus, we don't know what your HTML form looks like. check for errors, and your console.

Comment: well I have to go feed the horses.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Well I don't exactly want this in PHP, I'd prefer to keep it as HTML if possible.  Testing out what you suggested it doesn't work unfortunately as it ends up "breaking" my page.  I'm editing the above to include my index page.

Comment: you see this `case ‘DONE’`, again... if that  is your actual code, it's choking your code. That should read as `case 'DONE':` with regular quotes `'` and not curly quotes `‘ ’`. 2 different animals altogether.

Comment: You cannot mix PHP and JavaScript like that, plus your quotes, as @Fred-ii- pointed out, would kill the code. Make sure you're using a plain text editor for coding. For this you need to use AJAX to make your logic work, having AJAX calls for each discrete PHP function.

Comment: *Good catch on the mix there Sam* - @JayBlanchard I hadn't spotted that. and error reporting would have told them about that http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: *Eagle-eye Ralph!* @Fred-ii-

Comment: Here is a good intro to [jQuery AJAX with PHP](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html).

Comment: I see wonderful!  Will make edits and post results and properly vote afterwards!  Thanks all.

Comment: You're welcome Shea, *cheers* - sorry I myself couldn't help out, as I'm not much of a JS guy myself. I usually end up going on Google to find stuff already made up and where I usually end up landing here on Stack and Q&A's with accepted answers, or upvoted.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I've been on Google for 2 days trying to figure it out myself. I honestly and struggling to learn this stuff as fast as I need to in order to do my job but hey, at least I have a job lol!  I like learning and figuring this out, it's frustrating when you are running into dead ends for 2+ days.  Thanks again.

Comment: @SheaPrice *"at least I have a job"* - hehe, lucky you! I'm self-employed, so it's never the same. Some ups, some downs... some downs more than more hahaha!! but I like it. Well Shea, if I come up with anything to help you out, I'll be sure to let you know, no promises though but I'll see what I can do to maybe find you some other tutorials on this. I know the feeling of Googling for days; I've been there and for 3+ days, so I feel your pain, believe me. and you're welcome.

Comment: Thanks @Fred-ii-! Hey you can make better money being self-employed, plus you get to work from home on occasion!  Again, I'll be messing with this all day and let you (all) know what I can come up with for a solution.

Comment: Hi Shea, I noticed the invite for the chat but can't join in right now. anything to do with this question by any chance? if it's a JS issue, I can't help, sorry. I suck at JS.

Comment: It was for this question, no big deal that you can't join. It was mainly if you had any ideas about how to send multiple input values. I was hoping you could join the chat and I could email you.  I have a few that I tried and I was going to chat with you about them. I believe they're php but they could be html.

Comment: Looks like ultimately I am running into an API issue.The code @SonnY shared with me checks out and looks like it will ultimately work. I have to get with the application developers to find my ultimate solution.  Hope this post helps others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this new solution. This will send a post every 30 seconds containing only the input boxes containing text on them.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="Warehouse 3962" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <section class="w">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="small columns">
        <img src="logo.png" />
        <h3 class="green">Users</h3>
      </div>

      <h6>Warehouse 3962</h6>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="small columns">
        <form action="ajax.php" method="post" id="formSubmit">
          <table id="equipment-table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Equipment</th>
                <th>Amount</th>
                <th>Val1</th>
                <th>Val2</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <?php
              foreach ($results['tags'] as $equipment) :
              if ($equipment['category'] === "Part") :
              ?>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <?php echo $equipment['Amount']; ?>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center">
                  <?php echo $equipment['quantity']; ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <input id="<?php echo $equipment['number'];?>-val1" type="text" name="<?php echo $equipment['number'];?>-val1"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <input id="<?php echo $equipment['number'];?>-val2" type="text" name="<?php echo $equipment['number'];?>-val2"/>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <?php
                endif;
                endforeach;
               ?>
              <tr>
                <td colspan="4" style="text-align: right;">
                  <input type="submit" class="button" name="DONE" value="DONE" />
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function sendData() {
      var inputs = document.getElementById('equipment-table').getElementsByTagName('input'),
          data = [],
          name, val1, val2;

      for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        if ( inputs[i].type === 'submit') {
          continue;
        }

        if ( inputs[i].value ) {
          name = inputs[i].name.split('-val');
          val1 = inputs[i].name.split('val1');

          if (val1.length > 1) {
            data.push({name: name[0], val1: inputs[i].value});
          }
          else {
            data.push({name: name[0], val2: inputs[i].value});
          }
        }
      }

      window.setTimeout(function() {
        sendData();
      },30000);
    }

    sendData();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This worked!  It took me a while to get the stuff to interact with the API but that was on the Application Devs part not mine.  Thanks for all the help SonnY!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot mix PHP with JavaScript and why you set a timeout to 1000*30, that is equal to set a timeout to 30000 which means 30 seconds.
Then, you can use the 'require' attribute in the input filed to force the user to fill the required information.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="Warehouse 3962” content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <section class="w">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="small columns">
        <img src="logo.png" />
        <h3 class="green">Users</h3>
      </div>

      <h6>Warehouse 3962</h6>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="small columns">
        <form action="ajax.php" method="post" id="formSubmit">
          <table id="equipment-table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Equipment</th>
                <th>Amount</th>
                <th>Val1</th>
                <th>Val2</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
              <?php
                foreach ($results['tags'] as $equipment) :
                  if ($equipment['category'] == "Part") : ?>

              <tr>
                <td><?= $equipment['Amount']; ?></td>
                <td class="text-center">
                  <?php echo $equipment[‘quantity']; ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <input id="val1" type="text" name="val1”/>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <input id="val2" type="text" name="val2"/>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <?php
                endif;
                endforeach;
               ?>
              <tr>
                <td colspan="4" style="text-align: right;">
                  <input type="submit" class="button" name="DONE" value="DONE" />
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.setTimeout(function(){
      var val1 = document.getElementById("val1").value,
          val2 = document.getElementById("val1").value;

      if ( ! val1 && ! val2 ) document.getElement('formSubmit').submit();
    },30000);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey @SonnY no need for that kind of language.  That had already been pointed out in an above comment. Also I realize you can't combine them.. I'm looking for this type of If/then statement. I never said my code was right, I asked for help because I was aware my code wasn't working and I am loosing sanity working on the same issue for 3+ days when I know there has to be a logical way to accomplish this task.  I want the times for 30 seconds.  You need to read the question again to grasp what I am trying to accomplish here.

Comment: Ok, in this case I hope my solution will drive you to the right direction. Have a look at the code and see if it works

Comment: I don't want to force them to add information.  I want them to have the opportunity to add 2 text values to indicate what they want those parts for and where they are taking them.  If they don't I want it to time out after 30 seconds (an eternity for someone to input information) and then send that information to the database.  I also want this to then move on beyond my ajax page and go back to the index page (where the form is located).

Comment: Ok, I reviewed my previous post. Now, if the 2 textfileds are empty, the form is submitted after 30 seconds. Let me know if that is what you were looking for

Comment: I got excited that this would work flawlessly but unfortunately it makes me run into my previous issue... If I use the code this way it ends up generating ALL of the equipment ID's and not just the ones I took out.  This issue happens when someone, for example brings a piece of equipment back that they ended up not needing for a job. Thanks for the idea!

Comment: @SheaPrice right, that is because all the imput in the foreach statement have the same id. We're close to the solution then. The problem now is that you have 1 forn containing all the input fields so, when you submit the form, it submit all the input values. You can include the form inside the foreach and submit only the one the user is editing