# PHP/HTML multiple message POST issues on a JSON String

Tags: php, html, json

Presently my message goes out as the top string.  I am wondering if one of the two bottom strings will solve my [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34456073/php-code-isnt-allowing-multiple-input-values-to-send-through-my-form) of the data not having different values(val1/val2).

## Current Data Delivery:

{ "messagetype": "Transaction", "companyname": "c02", "warehousename": "wh2", "dir": "OUT", "date": "2016-02-23 14:48:57.048", "val1": "3", "val2": "3", "tags": [{"category":"Equipment","number":"P02020","quantity":"1"},{"category":"Equipment","number":"P02135","quantity":"1"},{"category":"Equipment","number":"P02137","quantity":"1"},{"category":"Equipment","number":"P02135","quantity":"1"}]}

## Option a:

{ "messagetype": "Transaction", "companyname": "c02", "warehousename": "wh2", "dir": "OUT", "date": "2016-02-23 14:48:57.048", "tags":  [{"category":"Equipment","number":"P02020","quantity":"1",  "val1": "3", "val2": "3"}]
{ "messagetype": "Transaction", "companyname": "c02", "warehousename": "wh2", "dir": "OUT", "date": "2016-02-23 14:48:57.048", "tags":  [{"category":"Equipment","number":"P02137","quantity":"1",  "val1": "2", "val2": "2"}]
{ "messagetype": "Transaction", "companyname": "c02", "warehousename": "wh2", "dir": "OUT", "date": "2016-02-23 14:48:57.048", "tags":  [{"category":"Equipment","number":"P02135","quantity":"1",  "val1": "1", "val2": "1"}]
{ "messagetype": "Transaction", "companyname": "c02", "warehousename": "wh2", "dir": "OUT", "date": "2016-02-23 14:48:57.048", "tags":  [{"category":"Equipment","number":"P02135","quantity":"1",  "val1": "1", "val2": "1"}]

## Option b:

{ "messagetype": "Transaction", "companyname": "c02", "warehousename": "wh2", "dir": "OUT", "date": "2016-02-23 14:48:57.048", "tags":  [{"category":"Equipment","number":"P02020","quantity":"1",  "val1": "3", "val2": “3”},{ "messagetype": "Transaction", "companyname": "c02", "warehousename": "wh2", "dir": "OUT", "date": "2016-02-23 14:48:57.048", "tags":  [{"category":"Equipment","number":"P02137","quantity":"1",  "val1": "2", "val2": “2”},{ "messagetype": "Transaction", "companyname": "c02", "warehousename": "wh2", "dir": "OUT", "date": "2016-02-23 14:48:57.048", "tags":  [{"category":"Equipment","number":"P02135","quantity":"1",  "val1": "1", "val2": “1”},{ "messagetype": "Transaction", "companyname": "c02", "warehousename": "wh2", "dir": "OUT", "date": "2016-02-23 14:48:57.048", "tags":  [{"category":"Equipment","number":"P02135","quantity":"1",  "val1": "1", "val2": "1"}]

## Option c:

{ "messagetype": "Transaction", "companyname": "c02", "warehousename": "wh2", "dir": "OUT", "date": "2016-02-23 14:48:57.048", "val1": "3", "val2": “3”, "tags":  [{"category":"Equipment","number":"P02020","quantity":"1",}]
{ "messagetype": "Transaction", "companyname": "c02", "warehousename": "wh2", "dir": "OUT", "date": "2016-02-23 14:48:57.048",  "val1": "2", "val2": "2", "tags":  [{"category":"Equipment","number":"P02137","quantity":"1"}]
{ "messagetype": "Transaction", "companyname": "c02", "warehousename": "wh2", "dir": "OUT", "date": "2016-02-23 14:48:57.048",  "val1": "1", "val2": "1", "tags":  [{"category":"Equipment","number":"P02135","quantity":"1"}]
{ "messagetype": "Transaction", "companyname": "c02", "warehousename": "wh2", "dir": "OUT", "date": "2016-02-23 14:48:57.048",  "val1": "1", "val2": "1", "tags":  [{"category":"Equipment","number":"P02135","quantity":"1"}]

---

```
if(isset($_POST['DONE']) === true){
    echo "Submitting";
    $dataString = "val1=" . $_POST['val1'] . ",val2=" . $_POST['val2'];
// set post fields
$post = [
'submit' => 'true',
'activity_name' => 'DataSendOff',
'params'   => [
    'Data' => $dataAsAString
]
];
}
```

Comment: Please don't bother editing the messages above, they are not code but raw data.  It is important that it stays the same so people understand how the string goes out.  I just want to know if I changed my outgoing message to one of the below options if it would allow multiple val1 and val2 to be attached to each equipment/quantity.

Comment: It definitely looks like json to me....

Comment: Also - why aren't you using `json_encode()` ?

Comment: @OliverQueen Yes the string itself is JSON but the form submitting the information is HTML&PHP.  I've tried attaching the val1/val2 to the same tag that the Equipment and quantity come through on but it won't send them out that way, or at all.

Comment: I guess what I meant to say is, why are you trying to send `JSON` as a string inside a `JSON` response? Why not just send it all as response `JSON`?

Comment: @OliverQueen what would be the point of that.  I use json_decode to get the message in my form the way I need it.  This is how the API needs the information back.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104449/discussion-between-shea-price-and-oliver-queen).

Answer (score 0):

This was solved by iterating through and appending to the 'Equipment' tag.  The API dev's had to fix something on their end as well.